# Changing Font when plotting with Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

When I plot a graph in gnuplot, I get the following message:

> qt.qpa.fonts: Populating font family aliases took 320 ms. Replace uses
> of missing font family "Sans" with one that exists to avoid this cost.
> Error: plot window (gnuplot_qt) not responding - will restart

I get that I have to change the font to "Sans". Right? If so, how do I do that? I have no idea.

Comment: That message is not coming from gnuplot. It must be from some system-level utility that manages fonts.  I interpret it to mean that the font family "Sans" is not installed on your machine.  But yes, you could probably also avoid it by specifying a different font to gnuplot: `set term qt font "Geneva,12"`.  I obviously don't know what fonts you have.

Comment: I plotted a graph in wxmaxima which uses gnuplot. When plotting the graph I received the message above. As far as I know, "Sans" is installed in my machine. Sorry for asking, but how exactly does the command work that you posted here?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to .zshrc...

```
export GNUTERM="qt font \"Arial,12\""
```

This fixed it for me on Mac Big Sur. You can omit the ",12" if you want to keep the default font size, but this may look a bit small in Arial.

The Mac font on Big Sur is called "San Francisco" or "SF" but I have not been able to find it by these names, or the earlier "Lucinda Grande". The best fit is probably...

```
export GNUTERM="qt font \"Helvetica\""
```